# Link caption of checkbox to a cell Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a checkbox (Form control), with the caption "Apple".

On cell A1, value is "Apple". When I click the "Apple" checkbox, cell A2 will become True. (I did this by Ctrl + click on the checkbox, and set it as =A2)

I need: If I change the caption of the checkbox to "banana", Cell A1 will also change to "banana". (Or, if I change cell A1 to "banana", caption of checkbox will also change. Either solution is fine)

How should I approach this? VBA is fine. Also open to using table objects if it presents a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your form is opened. If you start the form anew each time, just initialise the Checkbox Caption with the value in "A1". If the form is already open, you can use a Worksheet_Change event to determine if the A1 cell has been changed.

If you want to go the otherway, hide the Checkbox Caption and put a TextBox in its place. This way, when the TextBox changes, you can change the contents of A1.

Not providing sample code as I don't know what you have already done.